# How can I hover over a shape in canvas and change the color if I have multiple shapes?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to be able to hover my mouse over different rectangles and have the rectangle change color when hovered, what I have now works for the last rectangle but the others get cleared. The rectangles are created using a class/constructor, an array, and a loop. Code is below:

```
/*Variables*/
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    square;

/*Board Class*/
class Board {
    constructor(startX, startY, height, width, angle) {
      this.startX = startX;
      this.startY = startY;
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
      this.angle = angle;
    }

      drawBoard() {
        let canvasWidth = window.innerWidth * .95,
            drawWidth = canvasWidth * this.width,
            drawHeight = canvasWidth * this.height,
            drawStartX = canvasWidth * this.startX,
            drawStartY = canvasWidth * this.startY;
        
        square = new Path2D();
        ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
        square.rect(drawStartX, drawStartY, drawHeight, drawWidth);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill(square);
      }
  }

/*Event Listener for changing rectangle color and redrawing*/
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(square, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; 
    }
    else {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';  
    }  
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill(square);
  });

  /*Instantiate Array*/
  let b = [];
  /*Loop to create boards and push to array*/
  for(let i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    b.push(new Board(.05 * i, .25, .04, .03, 0));
    }

/*Function to loop through array and draw boards when page loads*/
function loadFunctions(){
    background.draw();
    b.forEach(function(board){
        board.drawBoard();
    })
}
```

This is my first project with the Canvas API and it's giving me a lot of trouble, normally I could identify the shape by class/id if it where made with a regular HTML element but I'm not sure where to go from here...

I've tried looping through the array that contains the board info but cannot get anything to work. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through your code, to get a better picture of what's going on.

As soon as you move your mouse over the canvas, the **mousemove** listener gets fired and executes it's associated callback function.

Inside this callback function we'll find this as the very first line:

```
if (ctx.isPointInPath(square, event.offsetX, event.offsetY))
```

So this if-statement checks it the current mouse position is inside of **square**. Well, the big question is: what **is** square actually?

If we look over your code a bit more, we'll find out that it's a global variable, which gets some value inside the **Board** class `drawBoard()` function as:

```
square = new Path2D();
square.rect(drawStartX, drawStartY, drawHeight, drawWidth);
```

Apparently it's a **Path2D** holding the rectangle of one of the bars - but **which** one actually?

Let's take a look at this function:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  b.push(new Board(0.05 * i, 0.25, 0.04, 0.03, 0));
}
```

and

```
function loadFunctions() {
  b.forEach(function(board) {
    board.drawBoard();
  })
}
```

In the first loop, you're populating the array **b** with ten instances of **Board** and in the forEach loop, you're calling each Board's **drawBoard()** function.

What does all this mean? Yes, **square** will always hold a reference to the bar, which's drawBoard() function has been called the last time - which will always be the last Board in your array.

To summarize: the only bar your checking in the mousemove callback is **always** the last one in the array.
So:

```
if (ctx.isPointInPath(square, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; 
}
else {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';  
}  
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fill(square);
```

translated to plain english means: if the point is in square's bound, set the fillStyle to red, clear the whole screen and afterwards fill one bar with red.

What you need to do instead is checking the mouse position with **every** Board instance from the array. It ain't to hard though - just make the Path2D a class variable of Board and inside the callback function loop over the whole array and compare the mouse position with each Board's **.square** property.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let b = [];

class Board {
  constructor(startX, startY, height, width, angle) {
    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.square = new Path2D();
  }

  drawBoard() {
    let canvasWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.95,
      drawWidth = canvasWidth * this.width,
      drawHeight = canvasWidth * this.height,
      drawStartX = canvasWidth * this.startX,
      drawStartY = canvasWidth * this.startY;

    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
    this.square.rect(drawStartX, drawStartY, drawHeight, drawWidth);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill(this.square);
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let currentSquare;
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    currentSquare = b[i].square;
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(currentSquare, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    }
    ctx.fill(currentSquare);
  }
});

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  b.push(new Board(0.05 * i, 0.25, 0.04, 0.03, 0));
}

function loadFunctions() {
  b.forEach(function(board) {
    board.drawBoard();
  })
}
loadFunctions();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=300></canvas>
```